# Typescript CLI runner

Tags: typescript, tsc, deno, ts-node

I would like to run a TS Script in command line.
Which option would suite best my needs: tsc, ts-node or deno?
Here is an unfinished script file for CRUD operations in Contentful CRM to get an idea what I am trying to do:

```
import contentful from "contentful-management"
import { Environment } from "contentful-management/types"

const ACCESS_TOKEN = "<content_management_api_key>"
const SPACE_ID = "<space_id>"
const ENVIRONMENT_ID = "<environment_id>"

const client = contentful.createClient({
  accessToken: ACCESS_TOKEN,
})

const getEnvironment = (): Promise<Environment> =>
  client
    .getSpace(SPACE_ID)
    .then((space) => space.getEnvironment(ENVIRONMENT_ID))

const sampleContentType = {
  name: "Blog Post",
  fields: [
    {
      id: "title",
      name: "Title",
      required: true,
      localized: false,
      type: "Text",
    },
  ],
}

export const createContentType = () => {
  getEnvironment()
    .then((environment) => environment.createContentType(sampleContentType))
    .then((contentType) => console.log(contentType))
    .catch(console.error)
}

export function addEntry() {}
```

Main Requirement is to be able to run a ts file in terminal.
It would be nice to use "import" instead of require (should work with node 16).
Can I have multiple exports in a TS file and run a chosen exported method from cli or do I need to have separate files for each script?
Do I need to adjust tsconfig.json and package.json (should not affect the rest of my project)?